# Any way to order the data frame by date of birth first then alphabetically in R?

Tags: r

I ordered the data frame by Date of Birth (column 1) from youngest to oldest with the following (there are 999 entries so just showing the top results)...

```
Original:
   DateofBirth     Name    today_age   october_age
1   2019-06-22  Thomas  13.516129   15.750538
2   2019-01-14  Jameson 18.774194   21.032258
3   2019-02-23  William 17.483871   19.717204
4   2019-12-27  Kayden  7.354839    9.583871

ordered_dat<-dat[rev(order(as.Date(dat$DateofBirth))),]

Output:
    DateofBirth Name    today_age   october_age
460 2020-05-19  Ian     2.612903    4.850538
523 2020-05-18  Sarah   2.645161    4.883871
380 2020-05-18  Jason   2.645161    4.883871
825 2020-05-17  Nora    2.677419    4.917204
```

I'm trying to find a way to alphabetize the already date-ordered data frame, but just end up getting the alphabetized version without the ordered dates:

```
alpha_dat<-ordered_dat[order(ordered_dat$Name),]

Output:
    DateofBirth Name       today_age   october_age
405 2019-11-23  Aaliyah     8.483871    10.717204
682 2019-10-18  Aaliyah     9.645161    11.883871
952 2019-08-14  Aaliyah     11.774194   14.032258
360 2019-04-28  Aaliyah     15.322581   17.550538
203 2020-03-21  Aaron       4.548387    6.783871
734 2020-02-13  Aaron       5.806452    8.064516
417 2020-01-08  Aaron       6.967742    9.225806
520 2019-10-30  Aaron       9.258065    11.483871
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Ha ve you tried `df[order(df$DateofBirth,df$Name),]`?

Comment: It works, but I'm trying to figure out a way to keep the reverse order of the dates so that the data is ordered from youngest to oldest rather than oldest to youngest.

Answer (score 0):

I think this actually solved the problem:

```
ordered_dat<-dat[with(dat,order(-as.numeric(DateofBirth,Name))),]

Output:
    
    DateofBirth Name    today_age   october_age
460 2020-05-19  Ian     2.612903    4.850538
380 2020-05-18  Jason   2.645161    4.883871
523 2020-05-18  Sarah   2.645161    4.883871
96  2020-05-17  Luna    2.677419    4.917204
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with arrange() from the dplyr package. Just make sure that DateofBirth is a date vector using as.Date(), and that Names is a character vector

```
dat %>% arrange(DateofBirth,Name)
```